# Do I have to define a default constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, class

In general, say I define my own constructor in such way:

```
class Numbers
{
public:
Numbers(int a, int b);
}
```

Would I have to:

1. Define a new default constructor? I know the default constructor no longer exists once I define my own but I didn't know if it was necessarily / recommended to include one
2. Do the parameters need to be included in the class? i.e. should I add:

> ```
> class Numbers
> {
> private:
> int ma;
> int mb;
> };
> ```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ***Do I have to define a default constructor in C++?*** That depends on how you will use the Numbers class.

Comment: A good portion of the time, arguments to the constructor end up stored in instance variables, so yes to question 2.

Comment: The member variables should be declared in the class declaration.

Comment: If you don't store the arguments of the constructor, what use can they be ?

Comment: Does it make sense to have a `Numbers` object for which you haven't explicitly provided values for `ma` and `mb`?  If you haven't specified them, should they be treated as `0` or something?  If so, perhaps it makes sense to have a default constructor that initializes them to zero.  But if it doesn't make sense, then don't add a default constructor.  For example, if `ma` and `mb` represent something that is not meaningful unless then they are initialized, then don't have a default constructor.  Semantics of the type are very important here.  Usage contracts are also important.

Answer (score 1):

For very simple structs/classes you can always try to write them as [aggregates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Basically:

- don't use private or protected members.
- don't user-provide constructors.

Then enjoy:

- minimal declarations for your structs/classes.
- simple direct-list-initialization.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/1v5Txv9zE)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <ostream>

struct Numbers  // minimal declaration
{
    int ma{};
    int mb{};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Numbers& ns)
{
    return os << "(" << ns.ma << ", " << ns.mb << ")";
}

int main()
{
    Numbers ns{10, 20};  // direct-list-initialization
    std::cout << ns << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. That's up for you to decide. A default constructor can be handy and makes life easier in most cases. But if you want the users of your class to always provide numbers, that's fine, too.
2. Yes, if you want attributes, you need to declare them. C++ doesn't magically deduce them from constructor arguments

Comment: Both points are wrong! If a object needs a state which only can be true if we have usefull parameters, there is no chance of default construction. C++ can deduce the types from constructor, that is how templates work! In older c++ we have user defined deduction guides and current c++ this comes without any handcrafted code!

Comment: @Klaus Re point 1: That depends on whether the programmer can decide on a useful default value. So it is up to the programmer to decide. OP gave us an abstract toy example. We cannot give guidance based on that. Re point 2: I have no idea what you are talking about. OP asked whether the object needs attribute declarations. Of course it does, assuming they want to store the constructor arguments.

Answer (score 0):

during compile-time 2 constructors are created automatically if given class contains no constructors.

1 - default constructor
2 - copy constructor

if you create one default constructor then constructor created automatically will be replaced by your constructor.

Comment: "during object creation": not really, this is at compile-time.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yeah that's the line, thanks.

Comment: Also the move constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use your `class Numbers`.

Constructors can be used to :

1. Allocate resources.
2. Force the user of the class to initialize objects in a certain way.
3. Check the arguments that will initialize the object and then to allow/avoid the creation of objects with a certain state (member variables).
4. ...

For example, if you have a `class date`, the class could implement constructors that check the day, month and year we passed as arguments.

```
class date final {

public:

    constexpr date(const int d, const int m, const int y) : d(d), m(m), y(y) { 
    
        // Check if the object has a valid state (valid values)
        // e.g: Is d equal to 0? Is m greater than 12? If yes throw an exception 

    }

    constexpr auto day   () const noexcept { return d; }
    constexpr auto month () const noexcept { return m; }
    constexpr auto day   () const noexcept { return y; }

private:

    int d, m, y;

};
```

If the user of a class forgets to initialize an object, the compiler will give error. If the object is initialized with wrong values that can be checked during compilation, the compiler will give error, if it is not possible to check this during compilation, then an exception will be thrown during execution.

You can implement a default constructor for `date` if you can initialize a `date` object with valid and default values (the default concept in this case is subjective).

```
class date final {

public:

    constexpr date() noexcept : d(1), m(1), y(2001) { } // The first day of the current century, for example.
    constexpr date(const int d, const int m, const int y) : d(d), m(m), y(y) { 
    
        // Check if the object has a valid state (valid values)
        // e.g: Is d equal to 0? Is m greater than 12? If yes throw an exception 

    }

    constexpr auto day   () const noexcept { return d; }
    constexpr auto month () const noexcept { return m; }
    constexpr auto day   () const noexcept { return y; }

private:

    int d, m, y;

};
```

(The above example is similar to the one found in the book "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++").

So, constructors and access modifiers allow you to implement a checked access to class members. We can use this to establish an invariant (conditions that must be met -that must be true-, e.g: the month of the date must be between [1:12] -inclusive-).

By answering your questions, use constructors when you need them and they are useful for what you are doing, when you implement constructors ask yourself why you do it.

Use the default constructor as your constructor, if you can provide default and valid values, implement a default constructor, so, if the user does not need to initialize the object with specific values, he can use the values provided by your constructor.

Sorry for my english.

I hope this will help you and I hope that someone can help me with my answer, I am also a beginner. xD

Edit :

An example of a "class" that you would implement without constructors and may not require an object-oriented approach.

```
struct vector2 {

    int x, y;

    static constexpr auto empty() noexcept { return vector2{ 0, 0 }; }

    constexpr auto operator+(const vector2& other) const noexcept { return vector2{ x + other.x, y + other.y }; }
    constexpr auto operator-(const vector2& other) const noexcept { return vector2{ x - other.x, y - other.y }; }

    constexpr auto operator==(const vector2& other) const noexcept { return x == other.x && y == other.y; }
    constexpr auto operator!=(const vector2& other) const noexcept { return !(*this == other); }

    constexpr auto is_empty() const noexcept { return *this == empty(); }

};
```

Or use operators as "free operators" (outside struct)

In this example, I do not use constructors, nor access modifiers because the "class" is simple and I have not established any invariant for the member variables (I could implement the "class" to ensure that the values of x and y are not negative, for example).